# Salesforce LWC: Not able to create record and not getting any error as well

Tags: javascript, salesforce, lwc

I have created a custom object and fields. and trying to create a record using `LWC` in Salesforce.

Here is my JS code:

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValuesByRecordType, createRecord } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ASSET_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Asset__c";
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class CreateNewAssetRecord extends LightningElement {

    assetName;
    brand;
    model;
    assetType;
    richText;
    pickAssetType; 

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ASSET_OBJECT })
    assetMetadata;

    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, {
        recordTypeId: '$assetMetadata.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
        objectApiName: ASSET_OBJECT
    })
    wiredRecordTypeInfo({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log(' getPicklistValuesByRecordType Info : ', data);
            this.pickAssetType = data.picklistFieldValues.Asset_type__c.values;
        }
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error Occurred : ', error);
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        if (event.target.name == 'assetName') {
            this.assetName = event.target.value
        }
        if (event.target.name == 'brand') {
            this.brand = event.target.value
        }
        if (event.target.name == 'model') {
            this.model = event.target.value
        }
        if (event.target.name == 'assetType') {
            this.assetType = event.target.value
        }
    }

    handleCreate() {
        console.log('Creating Record ...')

        let fields = {
            'Name': this.assetName,
            'Brand__c': this.brand,
            'Model__c': this.model,
            'Asset_type__c': this.assetType
        };

        let recordInput = { 'apiName': ASSET_OBJECT.objectApiName, 'fields': fields };

        console.log('Record Fields', fields)

        createRecord(recordInput)
            .then(asset => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Asset Created Successfully',
                        variant: 'Success'
                    })
                )
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                )
            })
    }
}
```

I am getting console log statement "Creating Record ..." in `handleCreate` function as well but no errors.
I have gone through the code several times and it seems fine to me.

If anyone can point out the error that would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.
The issue was in the 2nd line where I was importing the createRecord.
Instead of importing createRecord from `lightning/uiObjectInfoApi`, it should be imported from `lightning/uiRecordApi`.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import { createRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValuesByRecordType } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
import ASSET_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Asset__c";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
```